# What am I missing to accumulate in this While loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, accumulate

The loop runs fine once the condition of the price is met with "0," one time, but the loop doesn't accumulate the totals when the loop asks for extra item prices and quantities. I'm not sure what I'm missing in order to keep accumulating the number of items and their prices.

I've tried rearranging the code, mostly because I thought some syntax was out of order, but I think I'm just missing something to tie together the accumulation of the while loop.

```py
priceItems = float(input("\nEnter item price: "))
numItems = int(input("How many of item: "))

subtotal = priceItems * numItems
tax= subtotal * 0.0825
total= subtotal + tax


while priceItems != 0:
    priceItems = float(input("Enter item price: "))

    if priceItems == 0:
        print("\nSubtotal: " + "$" + str(subtotal))
        print("Tax: " + "$" + str(round(tax, 2)))
        print("Total " + "$" + str(round(total, 2)))
    else:
        numItems = int(input("How many of item: "))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the correct programming language tag.

Comment: As a hint though, when, where and how many times are you doing the calculation of the subtotal, total and the tax?

Comment: As another hint, 2 opposite conditions can't be met at the same time.

Comment: Also, the order of the input inside the loop is very confusing (and likely wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't reassigning the `total` variable. You are just printing the first iteration calculation instead of re-memorizing it in itself after each input, like so:

```
priceItems = float(input("\nEnter item price: "))
numItems = int(input("How many of item: "))

subtotal = priceItems * numItems
tax= subtotal * 0.0825
total= subtotal + tax


while priceItems != 0:
    priceItems = float(input("Enter item price: "))

    if priceItems == 0:

        print("\nSubtotal: " + "$" + str(subtotal))
        print("Tax: " + "$" + str(round(tax, 2)))
        print("Total " + "$" + str(round(total, 2)))
    else:
        numItems = int(input("How many of item: "))
        
        subtotal = priceItems * numItems
        tax= subtotal * 0.0825
        total= total + subtotal + tax
```

I don't grant the correct workflow of this script since I don't know the use case, but this is the problem. Refactor the right place where to redo the assignment and you're done! If it doesn't satisfy your problem, of course.

Comment: i think i figured out the precise use case ;) check now!

Comment: Thank you for giving it a shot. It did help accumulate the total, but as far as the subtotal and tax print out, it only prints the most recent input, instead of accumulating those as well.

Comment: if you have to track subtotal and tax, then you need two arrays and append every iteration input into it! in that case, you can also avoid using a total variable, since you can sum every element of both arrays. i didn't know your assignment, still hope you understood the problem. feel free to accept this as solution ;)